# How to use socket.io in node server using router, controller and index.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sockets, socket.io

I want to implement socket.io in my controller. How should i do that? I have following setup

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const http = require('http');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const router = require('./router/router');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan('combined'));

router(app);

// Server setup
const port = process.env.PORT || '8000';
const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port);
console.log(`>~~~~~~~~~~~~~< Server Listening on Port - ${port} >~~~~~~~~~~~~~~<`);
```

router.js

```
const controller = require('../controller/controller');

module.exports = app => {
    app.get('/greeting', controller.greeting);
}
```

controller.js

```
module.exports = {
    greeting(req, res, next){
        res.send({greeting: "Hello World!"});
    }
}
```

Is there a way to put following method in controller file and to access it using route in router file?

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('message', function(msg){
        io.emit('message', msg);
    });
});
```

I don't want to make my index.js file messy.

Answer (score 0):

You can set into express when initialising the `io` variable:

```
app.set('io', io);
```

Then access though `req.app`, like:

```
req.app.get('io').emit('some:event');
```

Comment: Can you describe it little more
@LawrenceCherone

Comment: where your defining `io.on('connection'...` before that line set it into `app`